# Error: ORA-12514, TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor

Tags: oracle, docker

I would like to ask how to resolve this issue

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7AYuD.png)

This was working properly before my laptop sudden shutdown.

The connection was working before, I had the correct username, password, and service name in my db connection.

We were using docker to start the service and we use Oracle XE 18.4 as database.
I tried stopping and starting OracleServiceXE in services but it's still not working. I already compared my tnsnames.ora to my colleague and we have the same configuration.

I can't easily delete my docker images as the database already contains many data.

Here is a partial error in docker CLI after sudden laptop shutdown.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wB5BF.png)

Any suggestion would help. Thank you.

Comment: I already restarted my laptop, stop and restart docker but it's still not working.

Comment: Our database and docker was setup locally.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 5):

ORA-12514 means you successfully contacted the listener, but the listener could not help you with your request.

You said: "Hey I want to connect to database service XYX", and the listener said: "I got your request, but I have no knowledge of anything called XYZ, so I can't help you".

Your second image indicates why. It looks like the database failed to start correctly, which means it has not told the listener that it is available.

Normally an ORA-600 means a critical error. You *might* be able to fix this by running:

```
startup mount
alter database recover;
alter database open;
```

at which point the listener should also end up fine.

Comment: may I know how can I run this query if I can't connect to the database?

Comment: you need to shell in, and connect directly, not over sqlnet